# Proving a complex quadratic equation

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification, quadratics

I am struggling with part b) of the following question [image]

I understand that part a) is the conjugate of α, but with part b), I multiplied the factors and obtained:

z^2 - z(conjugate α - α) + α*(conjugate α)

How do I further manipulate the middle term?

Comment: What are the two factors of the quadratic? Multiply them.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are the solutions to a quadratic equation, then $(z-a)(z-b)=0.$ What are $a,b?$

Comment: @Paul Thanks, I did that now, and I edited my current problem onto my post. How do I further manipulate the middle term to become 2Re(a)z ?

Comment: If $z = a+bi$ and $a = Re(z)$ then $a+bi + a-bi = ?$

Comment: @tktk Recheck your calculations, you made a sign error in the middle term.